# Как положить в Optional<> null по результатам работы stream

Tags: java, java-stream, optional

Предположим, есть сущность Box

```
public class Box {
public int id;
public String name;

public Box(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public Box(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Мне приходит список этих коробок, и я должен узнать имя конкретной коробки (оно может быть null)
Как я это делаю:

```
Box box1 = new Box(1, "1");
Box box2 = new Box(2);
List<Box> list = Arrays.asList(box1, box2);
Optional<String> boxName = list.stream()
        .filter(b -> b.id == 2)
        .map(b -> b.name).findAny(); //<-тута вот упадет

String name = boxName.orElse(null);
```

Получаю такую вот ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.<init>(Optional.java:107)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.of(Optional.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindSink$OfRef.get(FindOps.java:194)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindSink$OfRef.get(FindOps.java:191)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findAny(ReferencePipeline.java:548)
    at Main.main(Main.java:39)
```

Я знаю что можно решить задачку так:

```
Box box1 = new Box(1, "1");
Box box2 = new Box(2);
List<Box> list = Arrays.asList(box1, box2);
Box box = list.stream()
        .filter(b -> b.id == 2).findAny().orElse(null);

String name = box != null ? box.name : null;
```

Но мне кажется, что просто чего-то не хватает в первом варианте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `Optional` в принципе нельзя положить значение `null`. Можно только создать `Optional.empty`, т.е. отсутствие значения.

То, что вам нужно делается так:

```
Optional<String> boxName = list.stream()
          .filter(b -> b.id == 2 && b.name != null)
          .map(b -> b.name)
          .findAny()
```

или так:

```
Optional<String> boxName = list.stream()
          .filter(b -> b.id == 2)
          .map(b -> b.name)
          .filter(name -> name != null)
          .findAny()
```

Comment: Спасибо за полезный комментарий. Еще лучше если (name -> name != null) заменить на (Objects::nonNull)

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не написать проще:

- найти бокс по идентификатору при помощи `Stream::findAny` / `Stream::findFirst`, получив `Optional<Box>`
- преобразовать Box -> String при помощи `Optional::map`, получив `Optional<String>`, при этом `name` может быть `null` для некоторого бокса.
- для случая, когда **бокс не найден**, вернуть `null` для имени

```java
String boxName = list.stream() // Stream<Box>
                     .filter(b -> b.id == 2) // Stream<Box>
                     .findAny() // Optional<Box>
                     .map(b -> b.name) // Optional<String> - уже берется name
                     .orElse(null); // если не найден бокс, ТОЖЕ будет null
```

Comment: Спасибо за полезный комментарий

Comment: Это ответ а не комментарий